# SPOON Pentaho vs Java Standalone program

Tags: java, console, pentaho, spoon

I have written a standalone program to do the migration from one system to another which runs in multiple threads and processes them asynchronously (There are millions of records). "I have been told that I should switch to SPOON to do this job for better performance". Is this is the statement true?

1. If so I am curious to know how it is faster compared to the java program?
2. What algorithm or logic it contains to make it faster.
3. My understanding was it is a tool to do development faster like migration, or setting up scheduler, mapping the data, pulling logs and etc..
   I appreciate your response.

Comment: Pentaho is build in Java itself, what kind off difference it is having in the function you have written and Pentaho tool function can be compared by taking source of pdi and compare it.

On a high level there are multiple things can be don based on your scenario.
 
1) If you want to move data from one DB to another DB,you can use BULK-Loader utility of specific database which is almost 10 times faster then normal table output step.
2) You can allocate more RAM

You can go through Pentaho basics for more understanding,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically I am migrating the data from DB2 to Cassandra and it is not possible to directly migrate as we want to validate whether the data that exists in  DB2 is valid or not before we migrate to Cassandra.   Thanks for confirming. I have the same understanding that there is no much difference.